# Refer to a vector anonymously in R

Tags: r

Instead of writing one vector subscript operation a line, such as:

```
x.and.y <- intersect(x, y)
idx.x <- match(x, x.and.y)
idx.x <- idx.x[!is.na(idx.x)]
```

I could chain them in one line:

```
x.and.y <- intersect(x, y)
idx.x <- subset(tmp <- match(x, x.and.y), !is.na(tmp))
```

In order to do that, I must give intermediate vector a name to be used in subscript operations. To make code even more concise, is there a way to refer to a vector anonymously? Like this:

```
x.and.y <- intersect(x, y)
idx.x <- match(x, x.and.y)[!is.na] ## illegal R
```

Comment: The closest you're going to get to this is `Filter(function(...) ! is.na(...), match(x, x.and.y))`

Comment: what about instead of your last line of code using this? 
idx.x <- which(match(x, x.and.y, nomatch=0) != 0)

Comment: If the example is the objective and not just a way to illustrate the concept you're getting at, I recommend `na.omit(match(x, x.and.y))`

Comment: Ah, ```na.omit(...)``` could satisfy my immediate need. Thanks, mplourde. Meanwhile, I guess I'm also looking for a more functional way to write R code. I'll wait to see if someone can give some hints on that end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering `intersect` calls `match`, what you're doing is redundant.  `intersect` is defined as:

```
function (x, y) 
{
    y <- as.vector(y)
    unique(y[match(as.vector(x), y, 0L)])
}
```

And you can get the same result as your 3 lines of code by using `%in%`: `x[y%in%x]`.

I realize this may not be representative of your actual problem, but "referring to a vector anonymously" doesn't really fit the R paradigm.  Function arguments are pass-by-value.  You're essentially saying, "I want a function to manipulate an object, but I don't want to provide the object to the function."

You could use R's scoping rules to do this (which is what mplourde did using `Filter` with an anonymous function), but you're going to create quite a bit of convoluted code that way.

Comment: "Referring to a vector anonymously" is very much within the R paradigm. When you call `lapply(X, fun)`, `fun` is invoked with several different vectors, but none of those calls introduce a variable name visible in the code. It is generally considered good R style to use lapply, which does not introduce a new variable, versus a for-loop which introduces a new variable. Call-by-value is neither here nor there.

Comment: @crowding: I disagree. `fun` is not invoked on several different vectors in `lapply(X,fun)`; `fun` is invoked on a list, `X`, a variable name visible in the code. The elements of a list are bound to the value `X`. As I said in my answer, you either have to pass the object to the function, or rely on scoping within the function to find the object. If I'm wrong, please answer the OP's question using `lapply`.

Comment: ```x[y%in%x]``` is neat! Thanks, Joshua. It is good to know one more piece about idiom R.